# How to use emoji from URL in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to use emojis from an image url, so the bot can use the specific emojis across multiple servers. At the moment i'm having to upload the emoji directly to the server.

Is there a way to do this? I have seen multiple Discord bots which use external emojis, without it being on the actual server itself.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @Siguza Discord Nitro? I don't think bots need a subscription to use custom emojis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A Discord bot can use any emoji from any server to any server, it's quite easy in fact :

1. Go to the server where the emoji is
2. Type the emoji name as you would normally do to send it
3. Add a backslash on front of it (`\`)
4. You should see something like this `<:emoteName:emoteID>`
5. You can use it to send the emoji to any server your bot is on, supposing that it has access to the emoji by being on the server with the emoji you need to send.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this out now.